# Limit scope of #define labels

Tags: c++, c, scope, include, c-preprocessor

What is the correct strategy to limit the scope of `#define` labels and avoid unwarranted token collision?

In the following configuration:

**Main.c**

```
# include "Utility_1.h"
# include "Utility_2.h"
# include "Utility_3.h"
VOID Main() { ... }
```

**Utility_1.h**

```
# define ZERO "Zero"
# define ONE  "One"
BOOL Utility_1(); // Uses- ZERO:"Zero" & ONE:"One"
```

**Utility_2.h**

```
# define ZERO '0'
# define ONE  '1'
BOOL Utility_2(); // Uses- ZERO:'0' & ONE:'1'
```

**Utility_3.h**

```
const UINT ZERO = 0;
const UINT ONE = 1;
BOOL Utility_3(); // Uses- ZERO:0 & ONE:1
```

*Note:* `Utility _1`, `Utility_2` and `Utility_3` have been written independently

---

> Error: Macro Redefinition and Token Collision
>   Also, **Most Worrying:** Compiler does not indicate what replaced what incase of token replacement

{Edit} **Note: This is meant to be a generic question so please: do not propose `enum` or `const`**

**i.e. What to do when: I MUST USE `#define` & _Please comment on my proposed solution below.. __**

Comment: You're missing a `#define VOID int` somewhere. BTW I think that's a very confusing macro.

Comment: Are you asking about C or C++ - or both? The answers will be very different depending on that.

Comment: You should give an actual example where you must use #define then (as stated in the SO FAQ you should ask about actual problems you encounter). Otherwise it's theoretical and not constructive in a practical sense.

Comment: Please don't edit the question drastically. Your latest edit completely changes the meaning. For the future, try to post all requirements beforehand,.

Comment: @MSalters: You only need `#define VOID int` if you also have `#define Main main`.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore Roger that. Please comment on my proposed solution below..

Comment: @UjjwalSingh your solution is only a workaround. You shouldn't have to fix anything if nothing was broken. IMO you're abusing the preprocessor.

Comment: I want to avoid - future collision - It hit me hard yesterday. so looking for a best practice, clean - strategy.

Comment: @UjjwalSingh already answered with the best strategy - don't abuse the pre-processor.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore With my 'edit' - I must use pre-processor. what then?

Comment: @UjjwalSingh why must you use pre-processor?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two types of `#define` Macros:

1. One which are need only in a **single** file. Let's call them `Private #defines`
   eg. `PI 3.14` In this case:

   As per the standard practice: the correct strategy is to place `#define` labels - in only the implementation, ie. **`c`**, files and not the header **`h`** file.
2. Another that are needed by **multiple** files: Let's call these `Shared #defines`
   eg. `EXIT_CODE 0x0BAD` In this case:

   Place only such common `#define` labels in header **`h`** file.

Additionally try to name labels **uniquely** with `False NameSpaces` or similar conventions like prefixing the label with `MACRO_` eg: `#define MACRO_PI 3.14` so that the probability of collision *reduces*

Comment: As mentioned in my other proposed solution & as pointed out by @tenfour

Comment: Fake|Pseudo NameSpace mentioned by @MikeSeymour JohnBode

Answer (score 11):

The correct strategy would be to not use

```
#define ZERO '0'
#define ONE  '1'
```

at all. If you need constant values, use, in this case, a `const char` instead, wrapped in a namespace.

Comment: Note that this answer only applies to C++. In C, a `const char` can't be used as a compile-time constant, so might not be a suitable replacement for a character literal.

Comment: this requires that i must ascertain the `type` for each - previously used `# define` label

Answer (score 8):

`#define`s don't have scope that corresponds to C++ code; you cannot limit it. They are naive textual replacement macros. Imagine asking "how do I limit the scope when I replace text with grep?"

You should avoid them whenever you possibly can, and favor instead using real C++ typing.

*Proper* use of macros will relieve this problem almost by itself via naming convention. If the macro is named like an object, it should *be* an object (and not a macro). Problem solved. If the macro is named like a function (for example a verb), it should *be* a function.

That applies to literal values, variables, expressions, statements... these should all not be macros. And these are the places that can bite you.

In other cases when you're using like some kind syntax helper, your macro name will almost certainly not fit the naming convention of anything else. So the problem is almost gone. But most importantly, macros that NEED to be macros are going to cause compile errors when the naming clashes.

Comment: Of course they do have a scope, however it's a scope applicable to the preprocessor, not by the compiler.

Comment: They have a scope, from the point of definition to either a corresponding `#undef` or the end of the translation unit.

Comment: Preprocessor directives do have scope (not the same meaning as a variable scope, but nonetheless, they do)...

Comment: They have scope but not in any sense that's meaningful in answering this question. The scope of macros does not correspond with any scope in code.

Comment: @UjjwalSingh I think the voting for it does exactly that... :)

Answer (score 7):

> What is the correct strategy to limit the scope of #define and avoid unwarrented token collisions.

1. Avoid macros unless they are truly necessary. In C++, constant variables and inline functions can usually be used instead. They have the advantage that they are typed, and can be scoped within a namespace, class, or code block. In C, macros are needed more often, but think hard about alternatives before introducing one.
2. Use a naming convention that makes it clear which symbols are macros, and which are language-level identifiers. It's common to reserve `ALL_CAPITALS` names for the exclusive use of macros; if you do that, then macros can only collide with other macros. This also draws the eye towards the parts of the code that are more likely to harbour bugs.
3. Include a "pseudo-namespace" prefix on each macro name, so that macros from different libraries/modules/whatever, and macros with different purposes, are less likely to collide. So, if you're designing a dodgy library that wants to define a character constant for the digit zero, call it something like `DODGY_DIGIT_ZERO`. Just `ZERO` could mean many things, and might well clash with a zero-valued constant defined by a different dodgy library.

Answer (score 7):

Some options:

1. Use different capitalization conventions for macros vs. ordinary identifiers.

   ```
   const UINT Zero = 0;
   ```
2. Fake a namespace by prepending a module name to the macros:

   ```
    #define UTIL_ZERO '0'
    #define UTIL_ONE  '1'
   ```
3. Where available (C++), ditch macros altogether and use a real namespace:

   ```
    namespace util {
        const char ZERO = '0';
        const char ONE  = '1';
    };
   ```

Answer (score 1):

> What is the correct strategy to limit the scope of #define and avoid unwarrented token collisions.

Some simple rules:

1. Keep use of preprocessor tokens down to a minimum.
   Some organizations go so far as down this road and limit preprocessor symbols to `#include` guards only. I don't go this far, but it is a good idea to keep preprocessor symbols down to a minimum.

   - Use enums rather than named integer constants.
   - Use `const static` variables rather than named floating point constants.
   - Use inline functions rather than macro functions.
   - Use typedefs rather than #defined type names.
2. Adopt a naming convention that precludes collisions.
   For example,

   - The names of preprocessor symbols must consist of capital letters and underscores only.
   - No other kinds of symbols can have a name that consists of capital letters and underscores only.

> `const UINT ZERO = 0;   // Programmer not aware of what's inside Utility.h`

First off, if the programmer isn't away of what's inside Utility.h, why did the programmer use that `#include` statement? Obviously that `UINT` came from somewhere ...

Secondly, the programmer is asking for trouble by naming a variable `ZERO`. Leave those all cap names for preprocessor symbols. If you follow the rules, you don't have to know what's inside Utility.h. Simply assume that Utility.h follows the rules. Make that variable's name `zero`.

Comment: what if their are multiple headers - thus multiple #define labels.

Comment: @UjjwalSingh - You need a good naming convention for those `#include` guard, too. The last thing you want happening is to need two headers that both use the same name for a `#include` guard that is used in another file (that you also need). Naming conventions are important.

Answer (score 0):

I think you really just have to know what it is you're including. That's like trying to include windows.h and then declare a variable named WM_KEYDOWN. If you have collisions, you should either rename your variable, or (somewhat of a hack), #undef it.

Answer (score -2):

C is a structured programming language. It has its limitations. That is the very reason why object oriented systems came in 1st place. In C there seems to be no other way, then to understand what your header files's variables start with _VARIABLE notation, so that there are less chances of it getting over written.

```
in header file 
_ZERO 0

in regular file

ZERO 0
```

Comment: Names starting with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for use by the implementation:  you may not use such names in your own code.

Answer (score -3):

1. I think the correct strategy would be to place `#define` labels - in only the implementation, ie. **`c`**, files
2. Further all `#define` could be put separately in yet another file- say: `Utility_2_Def.h`
   (Quite like Microsoft's `WinError.h`:*Error code definitions for the Win32 api functions*)

   **Overheads:**

   1. an extra file
   2. an extra #include statement

   **Gains:**

   1. Abstraction: `ZERO` is: `0`, `'0'` or `"Zero"` as to where you use it
   2. One standard place to change all static parameters of the whole module

**Utility_2.h**

```
BOOL Utility_2();
```

**Utility_2_Def.h**

```
# define ZERO '0'
# define ONE  '1'
```

**Utility_2.c**

```
# include "Utility_2.h"
# include "Utility_2_Def.h"

BOOL Utility_2()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Using longer names helps avoid collisions as well.

Comment: Your first suggestion is standard practice anyway, and your second suggestion doesn't do anything to help name collisions.

Comment: Anything not needed by the users of `Utility.h` shouldn't be there in the first place, whether or not it's a macro. If they're only needed by one source file, then I don't see any point in sticking them another include file; and certainly not giving that a strange, unconventional name.

Comment: All __conventions__ are **created** at a point. Cleaner Code is the aim.

Comment: @UjjwalSingh that logic doesn't work. You imply that convention doesn't matter at all because if it's not existing convention then you are just making a new one of equal importance? Clean code looks for existing conventions, not blazing trails.

Comment: This is not "Cleaner Code". If you must, call that file utility_defs.h. Don't use a non-standard name that only you know the meaning of. Better yet, don't put stuff in a header that isn't directly needed in the header. Those #defines do not belong in Utility.h if they are not directly used in Utility.h. Even better, just don't do it. The easiest way to avoid collisions between preprocessor symbols is to not define any preprocessor symbols.

Comment: @MikeSeymour You are right - The #defs not needed in the header itself do not belong there. and that is what i propose in my solution. Now about putting them - in a separate file - that IMO gives `separation` and `abstraction` like what ZERO is - is obvious in the use context i.e. wether its a Char or a String or an Int

Comment: @tenfour what i wish to imply is that - new conventions **call for creation** IFF - they make things more organized and standardized.

Comment: There was my mistake - was not aware of it being the standard practice @tenfour. And for now i will have to settle with that - we shall make a new convention some other day :)