# Can I use define directive in a function scope?

Tags: c++

Can I use define in a function scope? Such as:

```
void run() {
  #define auto BOOST_AUTO
  auto i = v.begin();
  //...
}
```

Is the define still valid after the function? Can I make it local to the function? (Please don't tell me to use C++11)

Comment: `#define`ing keywords leads to unexpected behaviour! :)

Comment: `BOOST_AUTO` won't work when replacing `auto` here (it's a function-like macro, so it needs a comma separated argument list inside of parens).

Comment: @MichaelBurr Just wanna alias it. Make it shorter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scope (within the pre-processor) of a macro is from its definition point to either a corresponding `#undef` or the end of the translation unit. The pre-processor does not know anything about functions or other structures in the code.

Answer (score 1):

`#define`s don't keep an own scope as functions do. They are naively replaced by the preprocessor.

`#define`ing keywords leads to **undefined behaviour**. 
This means it is up to the compiler what to do. I assume yet that most compilers will get your idea and replace all occurrences of `auto` with `BOOST_AUTO`.

Comment: You mean "undefined behaviour," right? Otherwise, you're saying "it's unexpected behaviour, but it will usually do the expected..."

Comment: First two lines plagiarized from here:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641091/limit-scope-of-define-labels

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use define in a function scope?

Yes you can use preprocessor directives anywhere. The cpp isn't aware of any c/c++ syntax. Put a `#undef` directive before the function scope ends.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use but you also need a `#undef` directive where you function scope ends.

In your case it would result in an **undefined behavior** as you are trying to define keyword.